# Linux Virtual Serial Port for creating a device commuication

Tags: python, serial-port, virtual, virtual-serial-port, socat

I created a VSP using SOCAT with below command:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

where I was able create a serial device (19200,N,8,1) and send and receive data  using Python.

So I have to do the same for one more device with config of (19200,even_aprity,hardware flow in Python) when I do that its throwing below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py2.py", line 163, in <module>
    buffer += ser.read(1)  # this will block until one more char or timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 311, in read
    if self.fd is None: raise portNotOpenError
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port not open
Exception SystemError: 'error return without exception set' in <bound method BreakHandler.__del__ of <sig_handler.BreakHandler instance at 0xb719338c>> ignored
```

Guide me